# Getting ORA-01722: invalid number when trying to execute a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is how I create the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_FullName(P_CUSTOMER_NO IN number)
RETURN VARCHAR
IS
  var_fullname VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  SELECT C.LNAME + ',' + C.FNAME AS FullName INTO var_fullname
    FROM Customer C
    WHERE C.CUSTOMER_NO = P_CUSTOMER_NO;
    RETURN var_fullname;
END;
```

This is how I'm trying to call the Function

```
DECLARE
  var_fullname VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(rpad('Customer #',15) || rpad('Full Name',15));
  FOR rec IN (SELECT customer_no From customer)
  LOOP
    SELECT udf_FullName(rec.customer_no) AS FullName INTO var_fullname
    FROM dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(rec.customer_no,15) || rpad(var_fullname,15));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

When the customer table was initialized the customer_no column was declared type number(38,0). I think this has something to do with my problem but I've tried everything I can think of to fix it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators003.htm#SQLRF51158

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line.

```
SELECT C.LNAME + ',' + C.FNAME AS FullName
```

In SQL, we use `||` for concatenation not `+`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks!